# How do I let an error-message only appear after the $_POSTS are sent?

Tags: php, database, post

On a blog I'm coding the admin can edit existing posts.

I want to let an `error`-message appear when the `$_POST['title']` for e.g is empty(There will be displayed:"Your post should have a title"). I also do it if the subheading, content or category are empty.

The errors work just fine if one or some of them is/are empty. As soon I load the page to edit a post every error is displayed from the beginning.

**How do I make them only appear when one or some `$_POST's` are empty after the `<input type="submit .../>` is clicked (they shouldn't be there when the site has loaded)?**

This is the function in the `PostsAdminController.php` that checks the `$_POST's` and renders the site:

```
public function edit()
{
  $error = "";
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $entry = $this->postsRepository->find($id);
  $categoryFId = $this->categoryRepository->getOneCatFromId($entry->c_Id);
  $savedSuccess = false;
  $abort = false;

  if ($this->loginService->check()) {
    if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
      $entry->title = $_POST['title'];
    } else {
      $error .= "Your post should have a title.";
      $abort = true;
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['subheading'])) {
      $entry->subheading = $_POST['subheading'];
    } else {
      $error .= "A good subheading is nothing you should just leave out.";
      $abort = true;
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['content'])) {
      $entry->content = $_POST['content'];
    } else {
      $error .= "Your post should have content, you know, it wouldn't be a 'post' then.";
      $abort = true;
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
      $entry->c_Id = $_POST['category'];
    }
    if ($abort == false){
      $this->postsRepository->update($entry);
      $savedSuccess = true;
    }

  } else {
    $error = "You have no permission to do this, how the hell did you get here?";
  }

  $this->render("post/admin/edit", [
    'entry' => $entry,
    'error' => $error,
    'savedSuccess' => $savedSuccess,
    'categoryFId' => $categoryFId
  ]);
}
```

I really hope someone can help me with this, I don't know what I could to to let them only disappear when the POSTS have already been send..

Comment: What do you mean by “the $_POST's get send the first time”? Usually you would simply differentiate based on the request method, because _displaying_ the form is usually done via a GET request.

Comment: @misorude I have a form method=post in which textareas filled with the content, title etc. of the post are. When i submit the form I want to get the texts in the textareas(changed or not), if one of them is empty(the admin deleted the title for e.g) it should be displayed on the page..

Comment: Well as I said, check if the request method was POST. If it was GET, then that means it is the initial request that _displays_ the form, so no checks to perform in that case.

Comment: @misorude it is method POST. The error messages also do work, they're just already being displayed when I go to the site without doing anything on it.

Comment: _“it is method POST”_ - why? The page that _displays_ the form should be requested using GET, not POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if there was a POST action use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

in your case

```
...
if ($this->loginService->check()) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
       ...
       }
    }
}
```